# How to get a users email app to pop up and allow them to send an email through their own app instead of through the website that they're visirting

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on a website where there is a contact icon that should allow visitors to email the owner of the site. I would like for the user to click the icon and their mail app pops up e.g. apple mail, microsoft, etc. that allows them to email the website owner from their own app and not through the website that they're currently on. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

instead of having a link to forward to, you need to add `mailto:` followed by your email like this

```
"mailto:xxxxxxxx@xxxxx.com"
```